# How to get sales diff between previous and next month

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, group-by

I have table where I am having sales data for each day.

| Date | Sales |
| --- | --- |
| 3/1/2023 | 800 |
| 3/2/2023 | 300 |
| 3/3/2023 | 500 |
| 4/1/2023 | 300 |
| 4/2/2023 | 500 |
| 4/3/2023 | 200 |
| 5/1/2023 | 100 |
| 5/2/2023 | 400 |
| 5/3/2023 | 400 |

Expected Output:

| Date | Sales | Diff |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5/1/2023 | 900 | 100 |
| 4/1/2023 | 1000 | 600 |
| 3/1/2023 | 1600 | 0 |

I created a query to get sales sum for each month and I need to calculate difference between previous month and next month:

```
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, Salesdate), 0) AS TrendStartDate,
       SUM(Sales) AS TotalSales ,
       LEAD(SUM(Sales), 1) OVER (PARTITION BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, Salesdate), 0)
ORDER BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, Salesdate), 0) DESC) AS Sales_diff 
FROM salestable
GROUP BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, Salesdate), 0)
ORDER BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, Salesdate), 0) ASC
```

Could any one please help on this?

Comment: Can you edit your question and add some simple data and the expected output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a simple aggregation first, and aggregate:

- minimum date,
- sum of sales
  yet partitioning on:
- year date,
- month date

Then you can use the `LAG` window function to gather your previous sum of sales.

```
SELECT MIN(Date) AS Date, 
       SUM(Sales) AS TotalSales,
       LAG(SUM(Sales), 1, SUM(Sales)) OVER(ORDER BY YEAR(Date), MONTH(Date)) - SUM(Sales) AS Diff
FROM tab
GROUP BY YEAR(Date), MONTH(Date)
ORDER BY Date DESC
```

The last `ORDER BY` is not needed, it's just for visualization purposes.

**Output**:

| Date | TotalSales | Diff |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-05-01 | 900 | 100 |
| 2023-04-01 | 1000 | 600 |
| 2023-03-01 | 1600 | 0 |

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/lYWVRwQ7).

Comment: Hi @lemon,

I am getting error like Column "machine.rundate" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: In theory the last `ORDER BY` clause should trigger after the aliases have been assigned, but if that's not the case for your environment, you can either remove that line completely (as mentioned right after my query code), or change it to `ORDER BY MIN(Date)`.

Comment: Hi @lemon
 
I think you misunderstood my question.I need to calculate difference between last month sales and current month sales.But as per your code I am showing previous month sales besides current month sales.So I need to show rows values100,600,0 from top to bottom

Comment: It's enough to add `-SUM(Sales)` to the window function. Try the updated answer using the demo.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by applying the `LAG` function to only the rows with totals as follows :

First we need to get totals per month using :

```
select MIN(Date) as date, sum(Sales) as TotalSales
from salestable
group by YEAR(Date), MONTH(Date)
```

Then apply the analytic function `LAG()` to this dataset to get difference:

```
select *, LAG(TotalSales, 1, TotalSales) OVER(ORDER BY date) - TotalSales AS Diff
from (
  select MIN(Date) as date, sum(Sales) as TotalSales
  from salestable
  group by YEAR(Date), MONTH(Date)
) as s
order by date desc
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/WaD9pI2u)